# How to display components at defined position in JPanel?

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I need to display components at specific location. I'm trying to display `JLabel` like,

```
label1:

label2:
```

The code below however, displays them like,

```
label1 : label2:
```

---

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("My Frame");
Container container = myFrame.getContentPane();

JPanel jPanel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
//jPanel.setLayout(null);

JLabel jLabel1=new JLabel("Label 1 : ");
JLabel jLabel2=new JLabel("Label 2 : ");

jLabel1.setLocation(10, 50);
jLabel2.setLocation(10, 80);

jPanel.add(jLabel1);
jPanel.add(jLabel2);

myFrame.setVisible(true);
myFrame.setResizable(false);

container.add(jPanel);
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
myFrame.pack();
```

If the `jPanel.setLayout(null);` method is called then, it displays nothing on the `JFrame`.

How to display components at a given location in `JPanel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` layouts are generally a bad idea so it's best to avoid them. There are several layout managers that can be used for a vertical column. The most obvious would be [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) in vertical direction:

```
jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Another is [GridLayout](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) with one column and automatically determined rows:

```
jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

The `setLocation()` calls are unnecessary as determining the component bounds are the job of the layout manager. (Which is the issue with the `null` layout case: if you do that, you need to take care of all the component bounds handling manually - **strongly** adviced against).

**Edit:** As pointed out by @camickr, a useful resource when trying to select the correct layout manager is the [visual guide to layout managers.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: +1, for NOT use null layout. I prefer links to the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) rather than the API because it gives example of all layouts, plus sections on other Swing features that may be helpful for other questions. The OP should be able to figure out how to use the API on their own when given a class name.